# How to show picture cropping area

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jcrop

I have successfully implemented image cropping solution with help of this article [Upload-and-Crop-Images-with-jQuery-JCrop-and-ASP.NET](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/95/Upload-and-Crop-Images-with-jQuery-JCrop-and-ASP.NET). It work fine, but on page load, I want to show default cropping area. just like in below picture. I mean when page is opened that contained picture for cropping, it show default coordinates, however, user can edit these one.

I want to highlight 100x100 coordinates.

This is a closed solution http://jsfiddle.net/kLbVM/3/ In this example, when we click on button it highlights the coordinate, but I need the same thing, when page is loaded.

I am looking for same thing, just like in **linkedin.com**

[image]

**Edit:** Here is my page source...

```
<head runat="server">
    <style>
        #imgProfileImage
        {
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
        }
        .jcrop-handle
        {
            background-color: #333;
            border: 1px #eee solid;
            font-size: 1px;
            width: 7px;
            height: 7px;
        }
    </style>

    <link href="css/jquery.Jcrop.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.Jcrop.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Image ID="imgProfileImage" runat="server" width="400px" height="400px" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="X" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="Y" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="W" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="H" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnCrop" runat="server" Text="Crop Picture" CssClass="accentheader"
        OnClick="btnCrop_Click" />
</div>
</form>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var jcrop_api;
    jcrop_api = $.Jcrop('#imgProfileImage');
    jcrop_api.setSelect([0, 0, 100, 100]);
    jcrop_api.enable();

    jQuery('#imgProfileImage').Jcrop({
        onSelect: storeCoords
    });
});

function storeCoords(c) {
    jQuery('#X').val(c.x);
    jQuery('#Y').val(c.y);
    jQuery('#W').val(c.w);
    jQuery('#H').val(c.h);
};
```

Now its....
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. When you do '`Jcrop(element)`', `element` should be an `img`, not a `div` or any other tag, so move your `id="cropbox"` attribute from `div` to `img`:

   ```
   <div    >
   <!--  |________    -->
   <!--           |    -->
       <img id="cropbox" src="..." />
   </div>
   ```
2. Specify `width` and `height` on `.jcrop-handle` class:

   ```
   .jcrop-handle{
         background-color:#333;
         border:1px #eee solid;
         font-size:1px; 
         width:7px;    //explicit width
         height:7px;   //explicit height
    }
   ```
3. Enable resizing 'interactivity' handlers after `setSelect`ion:

   ```
    jcrop_api.setSelect([0,0,100,100]);  //default selection on page load
    jcrop_api.enable();    //enable resize interactivity
   ```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kLbVM/5/)

Comment: @MuhammadAkhtar Try to put all Jcrop related code in `document.ready` handler likewise in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLbVM/6/)

Comment: @MuhammadAkhtar Also if `jcrop-handle` class does exist in `css/jquery.Jcrop.min.css`, remove it, othwerwise you are styling same class twice.

Comment: yes, thanks for your help. All issues is resolved now, what was actually the issue, jquery.jcrop issue version was old.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/kLbVM/4/

So you want it to set the default dimensions on page load.

```
$(function(){
   jcrop_api.setSelect(getDimensions());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code on the "Shown" event of the form, and it will do what you need. Assuming you are using a .Net form to show the page, that is.
I think that there is an event that is called after a document has finished loading, which can be used to put the code in, if you need to load the page from the internet, first.

At any case, and whatever the actual platform, since the code works in an event(button click) it will work in the respective Form/Document event **after** it has been loaded and before is shown. It will not work in a "Load" event.